# Accept payments with stripe but How to Transfer using Iban or other means

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

Im working on a betting application I can accept bets with Stripe no problem which is great but how can I make payment to the winner.

Im wondering what kind of architecture to setup in order for this application to be built the right way.

When users sign up they can provide all their details and IBAN so that I can pay manually by bank sepa transfer if necessary.

I will also have their card information in stripe so I could pay that way but it seems like its not an efficient way.

Sites like gofundme.com etc seem to create a stripe user before payment but again im not sure how this is of benefit when it comes to needing to transfer a larger amount of money. The current flow is:

```
1) Multiple users will place a bet
2) 1 user will win
3) I need to transfer the winnings to that user somehow ?
```

Anyone got any ideas what the best way to build this kind of setup would be.. with Stripe.

Comment: Before putting any work into this, you may want to check that you're complying with Stripe's [list of prohibited businesses](https://stripe.com/us/restricted-businesses) for your country.

Comment: I was not aware of this thank you - strange though as gofundme uses stripe as does republic.co and many other sites that break these rules - i wonder how enforced they are of how lenient it is

Comment: gofundme is based on a peer-to-peer payment model using Stripe connected accounts. What you're doing with gambling is a heavily regulated industry and risky for payment gateways thus not everyone is willing to accept that risk.